# How does the async AG technology realise whether or not data has reached the secondary?

Tags: availability-groups, sql-server-2019

In sync AG the primary waits for an acknowledgement from secondary.

Where as in async AG the primary doesn't wait for an acknowledgement.

In the later case, suppose the acknowledgement is lost in the network, then how does primary know that it has to resend the data to the secondary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the network connection is lost, the secondary instance will reconnect to the primary and inform it of its progress.

Comment: Is it like, hey, I would like to have all changes after the latest LSN? Where LSN is provides by secondary.

Comment: Yep.  More like "I've hardened up to LSN=200 and applied through LSN=190", and the primary is like "Cool, here's LSN=201".

Comment: So in both sync and async is it the responsibility of secondary to ensure it has got all the data?

Comment: Yes, because the primary never goes offline if the secondaries are have an issue or become disconnected .

Comment: In async AG, with no automatic failover, what happens if the primary fails to harden the log to disk (due to say power failure), and secondary has received the log record and hardened it? When the primary is up again, then does primary redo or does the secondary undo?

Comment: Log records enter the Send Queue for transmission to the secondaries only after they are hardened to the log file on the primary. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/monitor-performance-for-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Does the log backup on primary not truncate the logs if the connection to secondary replica is broken?

Comment: It does not.  Those log records are needed on the secondary.